# Java regex pattern matching length

Tags: java, regex, string

I have input string as

```
input = "AAA10.50.30.20"

input.replaceAll("10.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5]).([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5]).([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])",
                        "X");
```

output is : `"AAAX"`

However i want the output as `"AAAXXXXXXXXXXX"`

It should replace the IP with multiple `'X'` which are equivalent to number of characters in IP address

Comment: "I have requirement to mask ip-address that starts with 10." - you said something like that on a deleted answer - I suggest you add that to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String input =  "AAA10.50.30.20";
Pattern p = p = Pattern.compile("10.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5]).([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5]).([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
String result = input;
while(m.find()){
    char[] replacement = new char[m.end()-m.start()];
    Arrays.fill(replacement, 'X');
    result = result.substring(0, m.start())
        + new String(replacement)
        + result.substring(m.end());
}
return result;
```

Comment: Implementation of my answer =D

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to replace all digits and dots by `X` call `str.replaceAll("\\d|\\.", "X")`. If you want to match the exact pattern use something like

```
str.replaceAll("(?:\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}", "X")
```

Comment: Can you give me regex that matches 10.* ?

Comment: `10\\..*`. But could you take a look on regex syntax? It is not a big deal, believe me. People will be much more motivated to answer your questions if you can show some efforts you performed before asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you search for the IP-address with your regex. That gives you 1 match - the IP-address. You then replace it with X, giving you AAAX. How about fetching the string matched by the regex instead, then replacing all digits with X?